# node.js some questions about store data

Tags: database, json, node.js

I am trying to understand how node.js works.

1) I would like to store data, but I don't know which method is the faster:
  -using sql
  -using json files (if this is a good solution have you got a tutorial for best practice)

2) A multilang website, is it a good solution to store translations in json files or is there a best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Handling JSON is faster with JavaScript than SQL because it's native so I would always use JSON over any other data format with node.js wherever possible. In terms of storing JSON, you can go for NoSql solution eg: MongoDB or CouchDB.

   This [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial) will get you started on MongoDB.
2. There are many options for multilingual websites, you can use Google translate or tons of other plugins depending on your requirements. If you want to store literal translations then NoSql DB will work fine. In terms of best practices, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487776/what-are-the-best-practices-for-multilanguage-sites).

Answer (score 0):

For Translation, you should ideally use internationalization module, whatever language or framework it is. In Node.JS you have i18n-node for internationalization. Your translation will be stored in JSON files. There are also other modules which can store your traslations in db.